# Workaround for Android 6.0 Permissions

Tags: android, android-permissions

Is there any way to get around the new Android 6.0 Permissions system if you need to build your App for Android 6.0 and use it on a 6.0 Device?

I ask because there are so many Apps in the App Store which are not asking for any permissions and that's kinda weird. For me that means there are two possibilities.

1. They all are not compiling their apps for android 6.0
2. They are somehow getting around the new permissions system using android 6.0

So is there a way around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your targetSDK to 22 will work on all device without permissions runtime, If your targetSDK is 23 than you have to set permission you can't overcome this.

Comment: @Mulgard You can't, you have to set permission runtime.

Comment: setting targetSDK to 22 may crash your app on certain situations in 6.0 I guess.

Comment: @VipiNNegi No your app working as it is, if you haven't use any api that only available in api 23.